# preg_replace to mask parts of a phone number

Tags: php, regex, masking

Ok so after having re-read over my previous post asking for help on this one I found I wasn't making it exactly clear what I was trying to do nor was I pointing out why. I have a site that I'm busy developing which may possibly display messages where people have left their phone numbers (even though this is stupid) and I need to be responsible and make sure should this be the case the numbers are masked. Firstly I need to search through the message text which is stored in a variable $messagetext then I need to use the preg_replace() function to mask parts of the number so its not clear what the number is so if someone were to leave a message and their number was "07921234567" it would appear on the message as "07**12*45**". How would this be done ? All I would like is to find out what function I'd use to search for the entire number (United Kingdom number) which may start +44 or 07 and what REGEX in the preg_replace() function as all i had was:

```
$extractednum = preg_replace( "/[0-9]/","*",$extractednum);
echo ($extractednum);
```

All this does is replace the entire number. The reason why I don't wanna do this is I also have another site I'm working on to do with social networking privacy and I need to mask parts of the telephone numbers I retrieve for my example.

Hopefully this is more clear and if someone could help me out with some code that would be great!

Anything is appreciated!

Comment: And if the user mangles their number into Zero792One234Five67?

Comment: @MarcB: I think he is trying to be as responsible as he can to mask the numbers, but if the user tries to bypass the filter then probably no can do.

Comment: Why not just replace the last 9 digits with `*`s? Then it will always be `07*********` or `+447*********` or `447*********`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the regex you are looking for is this:

```
(00447|\+?447|07)([0-9]{9})
```

To mask the phone numbers, you'll need a custom callback with [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback), like this:

```
$extractednum = preg_replace_callback( "/(00447|\+?447|07)([0-9]{9})/", function( $matches) {
    // This will return the number unmodified
    // return $matches[1] . $matches[2]; 
    // Instead, set whichever characters you want to be "*" like this:
    $matches[2][0] = $matches[2][1] = $matches[2][4] = $matches[2][7] = $matches[2][8] = "*";
    return $matches[1] . $matches[2]; 
} , $extractednum);
```

You can see it working in [the demo](http://viper-7.com/kpmd2c). For example, an input of `07921234567` yields `07**12*45**` as output.

Comment: I would write that first group as `(00447|\+?447|07)` to take all possible legitimate expressions of UK mobile numbers into account

Comment: @Dave - Thanks for the tip - I added your modified regex into the code. I also created a new demo.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how many numbers there are in a valid UK telephone number. Let's assume there are 11 numbers:

```
preg_replace(/(\d{2})\d{2}(\d{2})\d(\d{2})\d{2}/, "$1**$2*$3**");
```

This is not exactly a good solution, since I'm guessing that there can be phone numbers with different length, and people can put spaces in the number for visual purpose.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?PHP
function maskTelephoneNumber($phonenumber, $trim, $maskCharacter)
{
$suffixNumber = substr($phonenumber, strlen($phonenumber)-$trim,$trim); 
$prefixNumber = substr($phonenumber, 0, -$trim); 

for ($x = 0; $x < strlen($prefixNumber); $x++):
    $str.= ( is_numeric($prefixNumber[$x]) )? str_replace($prefixNumber[$x], $maskCharacter, $prefixNumber[$x]) : $prefixNumber[$x];
endfor;

return  $str.$suffixNumber;     
}

$trim = 4;
$maskCharacter='*';
$phonenumber = '555-666-7777';

echo maskTelephoneNumber($phonenumber,$trim, $maskCharacter);
```